# AttributeError: Unknown property yerr

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been able to get my plot with matplotlib when I plotted without error bars. However, when I try to add the `yerr` parameters in (to get standard error bars), I get an error `AttributeError: Unknown property yerr`

The erroneous code is:

```
for i in range (3):
    j=i+1
plt.plot([1,2],[totalcount_baseline[i], totalcount_treatment[i]], yerr=[yerr_list_baseline[i], yerr_list_treatment[i]], label='label%d'%j)
```

As seen in the code above,  1 and 2 are my x axis values, totalcount is the y axis values, and yerr contains a list of two numeric values.

My code works (displays a plot), if I remove the yerr parameters.

```
   plt.plot([1,2],[totalcount_baseline[i], totalcount_treatment[i]], label='label%d'%j)
```

Thus, how can I modify my code to obtain the error bars?

Comment: Most interestingly `plt.plot([1,2],[2,3], some_argument_I_just_invented=True)` doesn't work either. Mysterious!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pyplot.plt doesn't offer errorbars.  Use the correct function, [`pyplot.errorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html):

```
plt.errorbar(x=[1,2],
             y=[totalcount_baseline[i], totalcount_treatment[i]],
             yerr=[yerr_list_baseline[i], yerr_list_treatment[i]],
             label='label%d'%j)
```